# auto-resize a 'div' container to fit the image?

Tags: css, image, containers, resize

In a div I want to have a background image and a title. The title must be centered hrz and vert in the div, this is quite easy with display: flex.
But for this I need the container (the div) fit to the image that will change periodically. So the opposite question to the usual image to fit a container.

Comment: Add some code of what you've tried, at least something to work with...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

1. Add image to container
2. Set a mask with `absolute` position that covers the whole container
3. Set the title with `flex` inside that mask
4. The title will still be centered event with images that have different dimensions

```js
let currentIndexTitle = 1;
const img = document.querySelector('.myImage');
const title = document.querySelector('.title');
const titles = ['Title one', 'title Two', 'Title three'];
const images = [ 'http://picsum.photos/300/300', 'http://picsum.photos/250/350', 'http://picsum.photos/250/250' ];

setInterval(() => {
  const titleSelected = titles[currentIndexTitle];
  img.setAttribute('src', images[currentIndexTitle]);
  title.innerText = titleSelected;
  currentIndexTitle = (currentIndexTitle + 1) % titles.length;
}, 5000);
```

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.mask {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}
.mask .title {
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <img class="myImage" src="http://picsum.photos/400/500"/>
  <div class="mask">
    <div class="title">Title one</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Images will be from 200 px to 300px height and I need the container is resized, actually only the hight, so that both the image and the title are centered and the image (as a banner of the web site) is seen without scrolling (and avoid scroll bar of course).

Comment: I need to back @prettyinpink on this, I need some code of what you've tried because I don't think I'm getting the idea of what you are trying to acheive